# Syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Tags: php

I am getting the following error. I am trying to add data to database.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in localhost\site\admin\add.php on line 16

Here is my code:

```html
<?php

session_start();

include_once('../includes/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
 if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])) {
 $title = $_POST['title'];
 $content = nl2br($_POST['content']);

       if (empty($title) or empty($content)) {
       $error = 'All fields are required!';

       } else {
         $query = pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO articles (article_title, article_content, article_timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');

         $query->bindValue(1, $title);
         $query->bindValue(2, $content);
         $query->bindValue(3, $timestamp);
         $query->bindValue(4, $image);
         $query->bindValue(5, $demo);

         $query->execute();

         header('Location: index.php');

       }
}

} else {
   header('Location: index.php')
   }
?>
```

Comment: `pdo` Variables starts with a `$` sign

Comment: If you switch to an IDE (NetBeans, Eclipse, PHP Storm, etc.) it will show you where the problem is, without even having to run the code.

Comment: Thanks For Help Now Getting This Error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in ####add.php on line 69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was problem

```html
header('Location: index.php');
```

I had not added ; after closing brackets!